# Embedded C++ : how to recycle variables on stack using container/array vs dynamic allocation on heap

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

If I have a producer/consumer set-up where a large number of objects are to be produced and then assembled into a UDP datagram, before sending in a block (rather than sending a very small datagram per object), I would like to ask advice as to different strategies to avoid constant allocating/deallocating the objects as they are produced/consumed.

The software is to run on an embedded system, so I am interested in a strategy that would see a large number of objects allocated at system-start on the stack, rather than the heap during program execution.  I am thinking of the following, but would welcome advice/thoughts/criticisms please.  Is what I am proposing sensible? (pseudocode below).

```
class SmallCommonObject {
    // some sort of members here
    int member;
};

SmallCommonObject arrayOfObjects[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];

// this is a collection of pointers to objects that are not in use
vector<SmallCommonObject*> unusedObjects;

// here we store pointers to objects that are in use
vector<SmallCommonObject*> objectsBeingUsed;

// initially store all objects in unused collection
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    unusedObjects.push_back(&arrayOfObjects[i]);

// if unusedObjects is not empty, we can use thus:
SmallCommonObject *object = &unusedObjects.back();
unusedObjects.pop_back();

object->member = SOME_VALUE;

// save into used container
objectsBeingUsed.push_back(object);

// repeat above as required

// now do something with the vector of objects that are in use

// when complete
for (int i = 0; i < objectsBeingUsed.size(); i++) {
    SmallCommonObject *object = &objectsBeingUsed.back();
    objectsBeingUsed.pop_back();
    unusedObjects.push_back(object);
}
```

What about my choice of containers, are they optimal?

Comment: I think you're looking for object pooling http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html (search for it, many solutions online)

Comment: i would add reserve calls to the vectors

Answer (score 0):

Allocating and freeing objects at run time can be (relatively) **slow** and can lead to memory **fragmentation**.  This is of particular concern in embedded systems.

Alternative to dynamic allocation is to allocate a set of objects once and keep reusing them (without freeing and re-allocating the memory).  This approach is known as **resource pool**.  You can find an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8108/Template-based-Generic-Pool-using-C).

There are different types of resource pools based on their policies.  For instance, all objects can be pre-allocated at start-up or objects can be allocated on first use.  In C++, memory allocation and freeing can be done using **operators new** and **delete** (malloc and free in C).  Once allocated, objects are not freed.  Rather, the destructor is called to perform any object clean-up.  Before being re-used, objects are re-initialized by calling **in-place new operator** (a.k.a. **placement new**) that effectively invokes the object's constructor on an already existing chunk of memory.